# How to get region Format in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, regional-settings, machine-code

I am looking for a way to get the region format of user machine from pure js.
This is not the current language (I can get it from navigator.language) but the format user using.

Eg:
User machine language : English ("en-us")
User machine region format : Norwegian Bokmal (Norway) 
So machine use English and use bokmal for formatting.

[image]

I need to get this **User machine format**

Please help me.

Comment: There is no access to system user preferences. Localisation is available for strings, numbers and dates but is based only on language (which is not appropriate for many) and options defined in ECMA-402. To use the default language, pass it to *toLocaleString* as undefined, e.g. `date.toLocaleString(undefined, { /* options */ })`.

Comment: Change language to en-gb (or anything other than en-us) and you'll get sensible date formats. ;-)